# Trying a closure the wrong way?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what's wrong with the following code and why would it work when I do it using the second way. Can anyone please help me understand this?

I have this following Javascript code:

```
var clsFunc = function(prefix) {
  var id = 0;
  return function() {
    id = id + 1;
    console.log(prefix + id);
  }
}
```

**First way (did not work):**

If I try to call this function like this nothing happens

```
clsFunc('div')
```

**Second way (worked)**

```
var getId = {'div': clsFunc('div')}

getId.div()
```

Result:

```
div1
undefined
```

```
getId.div()
```

Result:

```
div2
```

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: It's basically the difference between `clsFunc('div')` and `clsFunc('div')()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clsFunc` function *creates* a function and returns it. So just doing

```
clsFunc('div');
```

...is pointless, because it creates a function and then just throws it away, because you didn't store it anywhere.

The second way stores the function that was created in an object property. That function has a reference to the context that created it (the call to `clsFunc`), even though that call has returned, which contains the `id` variable. When you call the function (`getId.div()`), it adds 1 to `id` and then outputs the prefix (`"div"`) followed by the new value if `id` (1, then 2, then, 3, etc.).

You don't need an object for your second way, you could just use a variable:

```js
var clsFunc = function(prefix) {
  var id = 0;
  return function() {
    id = id + 1;
    console.log(prefix + id);
  }
};

var f = clsFunc('div');
f(); // "div1"
f(); // "div2"
```

---

(The `undefined`s you're seeing are just because you're running this in a JavaScript console that shows you the result of calling the function; since the function doesn't return anything, the result of calling it is `undefined`.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this quick help. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm guessing revenge DV from the guy who deleted their answer at the same time.

Comment: Also great to get an answer from someone with 515k+ reputation.